# ImageView zooming is not zooming in or out

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, imageview

I have an ImageView zoom application ran on my mobile, when I first run it, the image work and the zooming as well, after that, I made a link button to the image view, with the same previous application, the image appears but no zooming for it and it doesn't move at all

Can someone help?

mapslocations.xml

```
  <Button
                        android:id="@+id/powerstationread"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Map"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Sites.java

```
package com.f.fa;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Sites extends Activity {
 ImageView imageDetail1;
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
 PointF startPoint = new PointF();
 PointF midPoint = new PointF();
 float oldDist = 1f;
 static final int NONE = 0;
 static final int DRAG = 1;
 static final int ZOOM = 2;
 int mode = NONE;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mapslocations);
  imageDetail1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.powerstationread);
  /**
   * set on touch listner on image
   */
  imageDetail1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    System.out.println("matrix=" + savedMatrix.toString());
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

     savedMatrix.set(matrix);
     startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
     mode = DRAG;
     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

     oldDist = spacing(event);

     if (oldDist > 10f) {
      savedMatrix.set(matrix);
      midPoint(midPoint, event);
      mode = ZOOM;
     }
     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
     mode = NONE;

     break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     if (mode == DRAG) {
      matrix.set(savedMatrix);
      matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
        event.getY() - startPoint.y);
     } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
      float newDist = spacing(event);
      if (newDist > 10f) {
       matrix.set(savedMatrix);
       float scale = newDist / oldDist;
       matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
      }
     }
     break;

    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

    return true;
   }

   @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
   private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
   }
   private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
   }
  });
 }
}
```

imageview1.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/powerstationread"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/powerstationwallmap" />
```

PagePowerstation.java

```
package com.f.fa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class PagePowerstation extends Activity {

    Button imageview1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imageview1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works in Sites.java because of all the code you have there to make it work.

You are doing nothing but setting the view in PagePowerstation.java

Actually put the zoom code in there and it should work.

Comment: I don't understand :) Do you mean putting the Sites.java in PagePowerstation.java?

Comment: You're not dont ANYTHING in PagePowerstation.java except  `setContentView(R.layout.imageview1);` Dont you think you need code to actually do stuff?

Comment: I'm lost :) ... Do you type more code in PagePowerstation.java for setContentView(R.layout.imageview1);?